# How can I convert Jquery code to ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

After multiple attemps to convert it to ReactJs, I did not succeed.

`Link to the code :` https://codepen.io/neverov12/pen/OJLYpzm

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look https://react-slick.neostack.com. This is the react version of slick.

Comment: Yes but I did not succeed to custom the pagination in "tiles-style" just like I did in the code

Comment: Codepen is jquery version, can you please share a codesandbox of your code, I will be able to help you. Just want to know, where exactly is the issue, Here is another example https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-paging/

Comment: Thanks you for your help. Yes codepen is the jquery version that is working, and I want to do the same in ReactJS : https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hugle-wtcht